# Ligth Switch with 4 wires

Tags: electrical, grounding

I removed an old light-switch and the following appeared:
[image]

I went to Brico, showed them the old switch, and got the one below.

I am wondering a bit how to connect it.
I am a bit worried that I only see 2 metal screws.
(2 lower right ones)

(It is quite certainly not 3-phase, but perhaps ground)

(Probably basic, but is there some way I can measure if something is ground or not)

[image]

Comment: I would think that the green wires are grounds and that the yellow and red connect switch terminals. But it might have been helpful to take and also to include a picture of the old switch before you unwired it.

Comment: Tested with a bulb.  CUrrent between Green and red, but not between greens and between red and yellow.

Comment: Somebody explained it was a dual switch setup.

Comment: It would be helpful to know where you are located.

Comment: if it was a dual switch setup then you got the wrong switch, you need a 3-way switch for that

Comment: You can imagine connecting 2 wires t one screw.